Azure App Gateway configuration for approved header list
Is there a easy way to manage the list of headers on the app gateway.
e.g. the list of headers allowed in the input and the list of headers returned in the response.
I know how to block one, but how to setup a allow list of headers.

If you need strict enforcement, use WAF custom rules to allow only certain headers based on specific criteria.  If you only need to rewrite or exclude specific headers without enforcing strict controls, the rewrite header feature and WAF exclusions might be more flexible. Basically, WAF custom rules are closer to an actual “allow list” in the sense of creating rules for allowed headers and blocking others. Rewrite and exclusion lists provide a way to manage headers without strict enforcement, which might be useful for less stringent needs.

What I want is that request with unnecessary headers should not be rejected at the gateway, only the unwanted headers are stripped of. The same would also be needed for response headers to have a global list of allowed headers and anything additional, is just removed.
I think with WAF, it would block the request. That is not the desired output I want.

Given that your goal is to allow requests to pass through but strip out any unwanted headers, the Rewrite HTTP headers feature in Azure Application Gateway will be the better choice as it enables you to configure a global set of allowed headers, removing any other headers without rejecting or blocking the request.

WAF operates with a universal Core Rule Set (CRS) that blocks certain headers by default. To let requests pass with specific headers, you’ll need to manually create custom rules or add headers to the exclusion list. This allows you to permit headers that might otherwise be blocked by WAF. Separately, you can use Rewrite rules to strip unnecessary headers from both incoming requests and outgoing responses. This feature doesn’t impact WAF’s blocking behavior but allows you to remove any unwanted headers without rejecting the request.

Unfortunately, there’s no single, centralized setting to manage both the allow list and stripping actions. You’ll need to set up exclusions in WAF and configure Rewrite rules independently for complete control over which headers are passed or stripped.

hope I was able to clarify your doubt. Putting it as a solution for benifit of SO community having similar query.

As discussed in comments, there’s no single, centralized setting to manage both the allow list and stripping actions. You’ll need to set up exclusions in WAF and configure Rewrite rules independently for complete control over which headers are passed or stripped.
Why?
WAF operates with a universal Core Rule Set (CRS) that blocks certain headers by default. To let requests pass with specific headers, you’ll need to manually create custom rules or add headers to the exclusion list. This allows you to permit headers that might otherwise be blocked by WAF. Separately, you can use Rewrite rules to strip unnecessary headers from both incoming requests and outgoing responses. This feature doesn’t impact WAF’s blocking behavior but allows you to remove any unwanted headers without rejecting the request.
Having said that, choose the approach that best aligns with your requirements.
Using WAF Custom Rules: Custom rules within the Web WAF let you simulate an "allow list" by setting specific conditions that permit only selected headers. This method is beneficial when you need strong control over which headers are allowed through, as you can define clear conditions in the WAF policy. Although there isn’t a built-in "allow list" feature for headers in the Application Gateway, WAF custom rules allow you to achieve a similar outcome by specifying headers to allow while blocking others that don’t meet these criteria.
Using Rewrite HTTP Headers and WAF Exclusion Lists: The Rewrite HTTP headers feature on Application Gateway allows you to adjust headers by adding, removing, or updating them as they pass through. While this doesn’t provide a strict "allow list," it gives flexibility in managing headers without enforcing rigid restrictions. Additionally, WAF Exclusion Lists allow you to exempt certain headers from being blocked or inspected, which doesn’t directly act as an "allow list" but enables selective filtering.
Check these out for better clarity-
Azure Web Application Firewall (WAF) v2 custom rules on Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn
Create and use v2 custom rules - Azure Web Application Firewall | Microsoft Learn
Troubleshoot - Azure Web Application Firewall | Microsoft Learn
Best practices for Azure Web Application Firewall (WAF) on Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn
